# How to add background color and border to google react column chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I have been following react google charts for visualization as documented [here](https://react-google-charts.com/bar-chart). I want a vertical bar chart so I am stuck with the material chart option.

However, none of the background color options apply to a material chart. How do I add a border and background to my chart then?

Comment: you can use the classic `ColumnChart` for a vertical bar chart...

Comment: @WhiteHat yes. I figured it out yesterday. Thing is, literally no documentation on google explicitly uses chartType="ColumnChart" option in any example. So I did not know that it even existed. Thank you for the comment though.

Comment: cheers! also, when / if you are forced to use a material chart, the following issue lists all the options that are not supported by material charts --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
chartType="ColumnChart"
```